# How to store my session MySQL with express-mysql-session

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, authentication, session

see code below. its not storing a session in my database. I cant figure it. I have executiion file app.js. I have everythin setup and running but storing sessions in database dont work.. I posted the same question before but got no luck...

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql2');
var path = require('path');
var session = require('express-session');
var port = 3000;
var app = express();
var MySQLStore = require('mssql-session-store')(session);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'tee tee',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MySQLStore(options)
}));


var connection = mysql.createConnection ({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '....',
    database: 'node'
});

connection.connect(function(error) {
    if(error) {
        throw error;
    } else {
        console.log("We are now successfully connected with mySQL");
    }
});

var options = {
    connection: connection,
    ttl: 3600,
    reapInterval: 3600
};




app.get('/',  (req, res) => {
    
    res.sendFile('home.html', {
        root: path.join(__dirname, './views')
    });
});


app.listen(port, (req, res) => {
    console.log('the server is running, ' + ' please, open your browser at http://localhost:%s', port);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears as you are using mssql-session-store (Microsoft SQL) to connect to MySQL. 
Try using the npm package express-mysql-session: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mysql-session

Like MySQL and MSSQL, there are many variants of SQL and SQL like databases so it is important you are precise with the database you are using.

Your line (below) should be the only issue. It is specifying the use of the Microsoft SQL session store package when you are trying to use the MySQL session store.

```
var MySQLStore = require('mssql-session-store')(session);
```

By changing it to

```
var MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
```

You specify the use of the mysql session store (Make sure you download the NPM package above first)

Comment: Your answer is just a link? Please add more details and have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll make it more precise.